# Does hazelcast cache for spring boot supported on aws lamda and eks, when deploy that spring boot service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-eks, hazelcast

We developed a spring boot service that uses hazlcast cache will not work if we deploy this service to aws. I want to know that hazel cache for spring boot supported on aws lamda and eks, when we deploy spring boot service ?

I want to know that hazelcast cache for spring boot supported on aws lamda and eks, when we deploy that spring boot service

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.